# is there any way to get data from http request?

Tags: javascript, ajax

use ajax to download a large file (binary), and the network would be disconnected after a centain time, but the http connection is established and status is 200.
before the network disconnect,i want to save the data that already received.
is there any way to do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just curl and get the body, or use postman if you dont want to code.